# Wso2 IS Managing Users and Roles with APIs

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

we working with Managing Users and Roles with APIs link [Manage user APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs)

trying to find function get specific user by username or email, but can't find,

which function i should use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getUserList()](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs#ManagingUsersandRoleswithAPIs-getUserList()) function.

For example, you can give claimUri as http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress and claimValue as the email address of that specific user.